# Akka and Backup/Fallback Actors

Tags: java, akka, hystrix, fault-tolerance, akka-supervision

I am coming to Akka after spending quite a bit of time over in [Hystrix-land](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) where, like Akka, failure is a first-class citizen.

In Hystrix, I might have a `SaveFizzToDbCmd` that attempts to save a `Fizz` instance to an RDB (MySQL, whatever), and a backup/“*fallback*” `SaveFizzToMemoryCmd` that saves that `Fizz` to an in-memory cache in case the primary (DB) command goes down/starts failing:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
class SaveFizzToDbCmd extends HystrixCommand<Fizz> {
    SaveFizzToMemoryCmd memoryFallback
    Fizz fizz

    @Override
    Fizz run() {
        // Use raw JDBC to save ‘fizz’ to an RDB.
    }

    @Override
    Fizz getFallback() {
        // This only executes if the ‘run()’ method above throws
        // an exception.
        memoryFallback.fizz = this.fizz
        memoryFallback.execute()
    }
}
```

In Hystrix, if `run()` throws an exception (say a `SqlException`), its `getFallback()` method is invoked. If enough exceptions get thrown within a certain amount of time, the `HystrixCommands` “circuit breaker” is “tripped” and only the `getFallback()` method will be invoked.

I am interested in accomplishing the same in Akka, but with actors. With Akka, we might have a `JdbcPersistor` actor and an `InMemoryPersistor` backup/fallback actor like so:

```
class JdbcPersistor extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof SaveFizz) {
            SaveFizz saveFizz = message as SaveFizz
            Fizz fizz = saveFizz.fizz

            // Use raw JDBC to save ‘fizz’ to an RDB.
        }
    }
}

class InMemoryPersistor extends UntypedActor {
    // Should be obvious what this does.
}
```

**The problem I’m struggling with is:**

- How to get `InMemoryPeristor` correctly configured/wired as the backup to `JdbcPersistor` when it is failing; and
- Failing back over to the `JdbcPersistor` if/when it “heals” (though it may never)

I would *imagine* this is logic that belongs inside `JdbcPersistors` `SupervisorStrategy`, but I can find nothing in the Akka docs nor any code snippets that implement this kind of behavior. Which tells me “*hey, maybe this isn’t the way Akka works, and perhaps there’s a different way of doing this sort of circuit breaking/failover/failback in Akka-land.*” Thoughts?

**Please note**: Java examples are *enormously* appreciated as Scala looks like hieroglyphics to me!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have a `FailoverPersistor` actor which consuming code communicates with, that has both a `JdbcPersistor` and a `InMemoryPeristor` as children and a flag that decides which one to use and then basically routes traffic to the correct child depending on the state. The flag could then be manipulated by both the supervisor and timed logic/statistics inside the actor.

There is a circuit breaker in the contrib package of akka that might be an inspiration (or maybe even useable to achieve what you want): http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/common/circuitbreaker.html